# CURL - How to follow a GET redirect from a POST?

Tags: c++, redirect, curl, libcurl

I'm having a problem whit a redirect.
I've a POST request that will be redirect into a GET request.
But Curl follow the redirect whit another POST request.
Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is normally controlled with the `CURLOPT_POSTREDIR` setting if you are using the "easy" curl calls. However, the default behavior according to the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTREDIR.html) is to change the POST to a GET unless you tell it otherwise. Possibly somewhere in your code you are using the following command:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, CURL_REDIR_POST_ALL);
```

You should instead call

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, CURL_REDIR_GET_ALL);
```

An alternative is to not follow the redirect at all, then process it yourself. This is a bit more complicated, but lets you have more control. This command will tell curl not to follow redirects.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0L);
```

Comment: I'm usng a version of CURL that doesn't support CURLOPT_POSTREDIR.
But what can cause the HTTP 302 found?
I need to solve also this problem caused by that redirect,

Comment: Sites use redirects, that's just a feature of HTTP. It is not likely that you can work around that very easily.

Comment: That option was added in libcurl 7.19.1, if you use an older libcurl than so you should upgrade for more reasons than this...